# Java 8 Streams - how to merge elements from the list with the same fields to one element and sum up

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have one question - I have List of elements A:

```
class A {
String fieldA;
int fieldB
}
```

I'd like to merge all elements with thr same fieldA to one element with summed up all values from fieldB this way:

```
el1 = AAA 5
el2 = AAA 7
el3 = AAA 2
```

Result:

```
one element: AAA 14
```

How can I do this using Java 8 Streams?

So in the end my list has to have less elements than at the beginning.
I have to find all elements with the same fieldA and merge them to one element with summed up fieldB.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yo can do some thing like this provided your class is mutable.

```
List<A> out = list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors
        .collectingAndThen(
            Collectors.toMap(ele -> ele.getFieldA(), Function.identity(), (a, b) -> {
              a.setFieldB(a.getFieldB() + b.getFieldB());
              return a;
            }), m -> new ArrayList<>(m.values())));
```

In this, you first will be creating a map of type

```
Map<fieldA, A>
```

having A(object) fieldB value as sum of all the fieldB values of corresponding fieldA value, and then simply converting the value set of Map to list.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This modifies some `A` elements of the source list. You might want to create a new instance of `A` instead of using `Function.identity()` as the value mapper.

Comment: hellWarrior - thank you. I've used your solution - works excellent!

Answer (score 6):

You may do it like so,

```
List<A> reducedAList = aList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(A::getFieldA, Collectors.summingInt(A::getFieldB)))
    .entrySet().stream()
    .map(e -> new A(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Rather than replacing the existing `List<A>` let's create a new list with the reduced A values. For that first create a `map` considering the value of fieldA as the key and the sum of the fieldB values with the same key as the value. Then iterate over the entrySet of the map and create a new `A` instance from each entry and collect it into a container. That's what we need.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! But I have one mre question - what if I'd like to group elements by for example fieldB > 20?

Comment: You may add this `.filter(a -> a.getFieldB() > 20)` criteria

Answer (score 1):

I'm aware you've asked for a way to do it with streams. The other answers show that approach. Here, for completeness, I'm showing another way:

```
Map<String, A> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
yourListOfAs.forEach(a -> map.merge(a.getFieldA(), new A(a), A::merge));

Collection<A> reduced = map.values(); // or new ArrayList<>(map.values())
```

This requires a copy constructor and a `merge` method in class `A`:

```
public A(A copy) {
    this.fieldA = copy.fieldA;
    this.fieldB = copy.fieldB;
}

public A merge(A another) {
    this.fieldB += another.fieldB;
    return this;
}
```